# How to call onkeydown event in a separate .cs file

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, blazor, blazor-client-side

I want to handle a `onkeydown`event in a **separate** C# code file. However, I'm always getting this error: *CS0428 Cannot convert method group 'KeyHandler' to non-delegate type 'object'. Did you intend to invoke the method?*

I'm afraid I'm missing the correct syntax. The target framework is .NET Standard 2.0. Here are my files:

**index.razor:**

```
@page "/"
@inherits blazortest.TestBase

<div tabindex="0" @onkeydown=@KeyHandler>
    xxx
</div>
```

**TestBase.cs:**

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Web;

namespace blazortest
{
    public class TestBase : LayoutComponentBase
    {
        public void KeyHandler(KeyboardEventArgs e)
        {
            // Do something
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: what is the .net version?

Comment: @viveknuna I don't understand, what do you mean?

Comment: which .net framework your project targeting to? you can right click on project in visual studio and see that

Comment: @viveknuna ah okay! It's .NET Standard 2.0

Comment: I am not sure, can you remove @ from @onkeydown and give a try

Comment: The event handler syntax is wrong, write :  `@onkeydown="KeyHandler"`

Comment: The inherits statement is wrong to, it should be : `@inherits blazortest.IndexBase`

Comment: @aguafrommars That's correct, @onkeydown="KeyHandler". Write it as an answer, then you get score! ;)  The "IndexBase" was an error when I wrote the question.

Comment: @askolotl done.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code should be :

```cs
@page "/"
@inherits blazortest.TestBase

<div tabindex="0" @onkeydown="KeyHandler">
    xxx
</div>
```

```cs
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Web;

namespace blazortest
{
    public class TestBase : LayoutComponentBase
    {
        public void KeyHandler(KeyboardEventArgs e)
        {
            // Do something
        }
    }
}
```